# itext7 draw % filled circle

Tags: canvas, draw, itext7

I need to draw a circle that's filled by a certain %. I tried the arc, but that's just cutting the circle weirdly. The end result should look something like [this](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1DQPmJcio-iMLWFO98LpLsai5Wp6bNo7j). No idea how I can get this done when I can't even draw an x% filled circle. I can draw the rest of what I want just fine by stacking colored and white circles, but that's no use if I have to cut on the top layer weirdly.

Code from what i tried:

```
int tx=300;
    int ty=200;
    int tr=100;
    PdfCanvas canvas1 = new PdfCanvas(pdfPage);
    canvas1.setColor(Color.GRAY, true);
    canvas1.circle(tx, ty, tr);
    canvas1.fill();

    PdfCanvas canvas11 = new PdfCanvas(pdfPage);
    canvas11.setColor(Color.WHITE, true);
    canvas11.circle(tx, ty, tr-10);
    canvas11.fill();

    PdfCanvas canvas2 = new PdfCanvas(pdfPage);
    canvas2.setColor(Color.GREEN, true);
    canvas2.arc(tx-tr-10, ty-tr-10, tx+tr+10, ty+tr+10,90,87);//87 is just for testing
    //canvas2.circle(tx, ty, tr+20);
    canvas2.fill();

    PdfCanvas canvas22 = new PdfCanvas(pdfPage);
    canvas22.setColor(Color.WHITE, true);
    canvas22.circle(tx, ty, tr-20);
    canvas22.fill();
```

Comment: Please can you show the code for what you actually tried?

Comment: included it, but well its not much xD

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I see that you are using iText `7.0.x` version (by the fact that the color constants are in `Color` class), while `7.1.x` has been out there for quite a while already and `7.1.4` is the latest release at the moment. I recommend that you switch to the new line as early into the project as you can because this is the version line that is actively maintained at the moment. The difference in API is very small between 7.0 and 7.1, but in your case you will have to use `ColorConstants` class instead of `Color`.

Also there is no need to create new `PdfCanvas` instances each time. You can use one instance. If needed, you can call `saveState()` and `restoreState()` so that your setting of color, line width etc only apply to operations between saving and restoring the state.

You approach with `PdfCanvas#arc` is actually a valid one, but you need to look into stroking the arc instead of filling it. If I modify your code a bit:

```
int centerX = 300;
int centerY = 200;
int radius = 100;
float fillPercent = 80;
float circleThickness = 10;
float arcThickness = 15;

PdfCanvas canvas = new PdfCanvas(pdfPage);
canvas.setFillColor(ColorConstants.GRAY);
canvas.circle(centerX, centerY, radius);
canvas.fill();

canvas.setFillColor(ColorConstants.WHITE);
canvas.circle(centerX, centerY, radius - circleThickness);
canvas.fill();

canvas.setStrokeColor(ColorConstants.GREEN);
canvas.setLineWidth(arcThickness);
canvas.arc(centerX - radius + circleThickness / 2, centerY - radius + circleThickness / 2,
        centerX + radius - circleThickness / 2, centerY + radius - circleThickness / 2, 90, -fillPercent / 100 * 360.);
canvas.stroke();
```

I can achieve the following result:

[image: resultant arc]